# Error in filter(., max(max_weight)) : object 'year_weight' not found

Tags: r

- 

every time I try running this I keep getting this error  'Error in filter(., max(max_weight)) :object 'year_weight' not found'

*

```
  year_weight <- surveys %>% 
    group_by(year, genus, species_id ) %>% 
    filter(weight == max(weight)) %>%
    summarise(max_weight = max(weight))
```

Comment: Is there other code preceding this that is incomplete, e.g. with a trailing `%>%` or open parentheses? I suspect an operation is encountering `year_weight` outside what you've shared here.

Comment: Greetings! It would be helpful to have a minimal reproducible dataset included in your question. One way of doing that is by using the `dput` command. You can find out how to do this here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg